# epplus Excel Duration formula not working in C#

Tags: c#, excel-formula, epplus, duration

I have wrote the below code for duration calc in `C#`

```
ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
workSheet.View.RightToLeft = true;

var formula="MDURATION(43860.3507195718,44233,0.2,0.199014876362008,2,3)";

workSheet.Cells["Z8"].Formula = formula;
workSheet.Cells["Z8"].Calculate();
var result= (workSheet.Cells["Z8"].Value);
```

This formula works in Excel but does not work in this code
Finally the value of the result variable becomes  `{#NAME?}`.
But its value in Excel is `.803`

Comment: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formula-Calculation has an advice on how to attach a logger to see where the formula goes wrong - adding its output to the question may be helpful

Comment: Note that the [list of supported functions](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Supported-Functions) doesn't contain MDURATION

Comment: Also note that the locale to be used is always en! , Vs ; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments current version of the `epplus` does not support the `MDURATION` function.

However, you could use another `NuGet Package`: [`ExcelFinancialFunctions`](http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelFinancialFunctions/) as follows:

```
using Excel.FinancialFunctions;

//...

//var formula = "MDURATION(43860.3507195718,44233,0.2,0.199014876362008,2,3)";

DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
double modifiedDuration = Financial.MDuration(
    start.AddDays(43860.3507195718), 
    start.AddDays(44233), 
    0.2, 
    0.199014876362008,
    (Frequency)2, 
    (DayCountBasis)3);

workSheet.Cells["Z8"].Value = modifiedDuration;
```